# Multiple Output Files for Hadoop Streaming with Python Mapper

Tags: python, hadoop

I am looking for a little clarification on the the answers to this question here:

[Generating Separate Output files in Hadoop Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626786/generating-separate-output-files-in-hadoop-streaming)

My use case is as follows:

I have a map-only mapreduce job that takes an input file, does a lot of parsing and munging, and then writes back out.  However, certain lines may or may not be in an incorrect format, and if that is the case, I would like to write the original line to a separate file.

It seems that one way to do this would be to prepend the name of the file to the line I am printing and use the multipleOutputFormat parameter.  For example, if I originally had:

```
if line_is_valid(line):
    print name + '\t' + comments
```

I could instead do:

```
if line_is_valid(line):
    print valid_file_name + '\t' + name + '\t' + comments
else:
    print err_file_name + '\t' + line
```

The only problem I have with this solution is that I don't want the file_name to appear as the first column in the textfiles.  I suppose I could then run another job to strip out the first column of each file, but that seems kind of silly.  So:

1) Is this the correct way to manage multiple output files with a python mapreduce job?

2) What is the best way to get rid of that initial column?

Comment: You question is interesting. I have attempted to answer. Hope it makes sense. Please do reply. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do something like the following, but it involves a little Java compiling, which I think shouldn't be a problem, if you want your use case done anyway with Python-
From Python, as far as I know it's not directly possible to skip the filename from the final output as your use case demands in a single job. But what's shown below can make it possible with ease!

Here is the Java class that's need to compiled -

```
package com.custom;
 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleTextOutputFormat;

 public class CustomMultiOutputFormat extends MultipleTextOutputFormat<Text, Text> {
        /**
        * Use they key as part of the path for the final output file.
        */
       @Override
       protected String generateFileNameForKeyValue(Text key, Text value, String leaf) {
             return new Path(key.toString(), leaf).toString();
       }

       /**
        * We discard the key as per your requirement
        */
       @Override
       protected Text generateActualKey(Text key, Text value) {
             return null;
       }
 }
```

**Steps to compile:**

1. Save the text to a file exactly (no different name)
   **CustomMultiOutputFormat.java**
2. While you are in the directory where the above saved file is, type -

   `$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac -cp $(hadoop classpath) -d . CustomMultiOutputFormat.java`
3. Make sure JAVA_HOME is set to /path/to/your/SUNJDK before attempting
   the above command.
4. Make your custom.jar file using (type exactly) -

   `$JAVA_HOME/bin/jar cvf custom.jar com/custom/CustomMultiOutputFormat.class`
5. Finally, run your job like -

   `hadoop jar /path/to/your/hadoop-streaming-*.jar -libjars custom.jar -outputformat com.custom.CustomMultiOutputFormat -file your_script.py -input inputpath --numReduceTasks 0 -output outputpath -mapper your_script.py`

After doing these you should see two directories inside your **outputpath** one with **valid_file_name** and other with **err_file_name**. All records having valid_file_name as a tag will go to valid_file_name directory and all records having err_file_name would go to err_file_name directory.

I hope all these makes sense.

Comment: I had hoped to do it in pure python through the streaming API [without defining a custom output format], but like you said, I don't think that it's actually possible.  Thanks for a real solution!

Comment: Yeah, for Python there are ways around such as doing a shelling out and executing the hadoop command, but I don't think that's a clean and a good way to do what you want.

Comment: What happens to the separator between the key and the value? Are the lines prepended with it?

Comment: could you please explain leaf in generateFileNameForKeyValue method?

Comment: @slayton: The separator should not appear in ideal situation. If you see that, probably you can override the default key value separator to a empty string or something. There should be a property to do that.

Comment: @adarshaU: Leaf is last part of the file name you see. Like part-xxxxx by default in the MapReduce HDFS output.

Comment: When i do this my mapreduce program is throwing an error on line: print rec[0]+"\t"+line IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe. All the other compile commands run fine(Although i don't know what they do exactly)...

Comment: Specifically Iam getting an error: Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=ra88114, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x