# Hadoop Streaming - How to output to multiple directories/files from reducer using Python

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, mapreduce

I have to write output to multiple directories based on some criteria. I know it can be done using `MultipleOutputFormat` class in Java.

I want to know, how can we achieve this in Python without using external libraries like Pydoop etc.

Output should look something like this:

```
a1/b1/c1/file1,
a1/b1/c2/file2,
a1/b2/c1/file3,
a2/b1/c1/file4,
a2/b2/c2/file5,
a2/b2/c3/file6
```

Comment: You can refer this: > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541503/multiple-output-files-for-hadoop-streaming-with-python-mapper

Comment: Thanks for your input. Wrote a custom java utility to do this. Very similar to what you referred.