# Multipleoutput file in hadoop streaming

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I followed this post:
[Multiple Output Files for Hadoop Streaming with Python Mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541503/multiple-output-files-for-hadoop-streaming-with-python-mapper)
for generating Multipleoutput file in hadoop streaming and i am getting that too.
So i wanted my structure like that:
date--:

---code=1
---code=2
---code=3

date--:

:
:

But inside code=1 and other directories everything is written to one file only and since my data is very large my job is taking very large time for completion.
Any workaround for that???

```
package com.custom;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleTextOutputFormat;
import java.lang.*;

public class CustomMultiOutputFormat extends MultipleTextOutputFormat<Text, Text> {

       @Override
        protected String generateFileNameForKeyValue(Text key, Text value, String leaf) {
        String key_temp,date,code,key_final;
        key_temp=key.toString();

        String[] arr=key_temp.split("/");
        date="date=" +arr[0];
        code ="code="+arr[1];
        key_final=date+"/"+code;
        Text t1 = new Text(key_final);  
        return new Path(t1.toString(), leaf).toString();
        }
        @Override
        protected Text generateActualKey(Text key, Text value) {
        return null;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Don't you forget to add leaf at 'generateFileNameForKeyValue' as described in your linked answer? it is a suffix like 'part-0000' that is unique for each map task. Please post code of your OutputFormat to get more details.

Comment: i have posted code as well

Comment: It looks correct, how many mappers in your job? Is it possible that all data with the same key goes into 1 split? what is the name of the file inside `code=* `directories?